# Bootstrap Single Page Full Screen Layout Responsive Height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a single page full screen layout using Bootstrap 3 where the height of the main body is responsive.

The page is going to be displayed in Kiosk mode displaying 3 panels which display different messages, but as the site is going to be displayed on multiple screens of different sizes I am wanting to get the main to be responsive in height.

https://jsfiddle.net/gokcLvtv/7/

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row header">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
      LOGO
    </div>
  </div><!-- Header-->

  <div class="row main">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="well">Panel One</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="well">Panel Two</div>    
      <div class="well">Panel Three</div>
    </div>
  </div><!--main-->

  <div class="row footer">
    <div class="col-xs-12">&copy; Copyright 2016</div>  
  </div><!--footer-->

</div><!--container-->
```

As you can see I have had to specify a height of the main content to get the cols to be 100% and then the .wells inside the column. But I am wanting this to be 100%.

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/9upm5h3b/1/) what you want ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the vw value for horizontal and vertical resizing.
[For example](https://jsfiddle.net/gokcLvtv/10/)

HTML

```
<div class="main">
<div class="well">
Panel one
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main {
   border: 1px solid red;
   height: 75vw;
}

.well {
   width: 30vw;
   height: 30vw;
   margin: 1vw;
}
```

It's easy to translate from px to vw. Every 1 vw is 10 pixels.

Comment: This still requires you to specify the height of the outer container, so if the screen sizes are different the height in vw would still need to be different wouldn't it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help with the vw ... I have managed to achieve this using vh for the height..

I have created an example for anyone who would like to use this in the future - [here](https://jsfiddle.net/44nL4q6q/)

Using the same layout

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="well">Header</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- main -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 main">
                <div class="well">
                    Main Panel
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4 side-bar">
                <div class="well">
                  Side Panel One
                </div>

                <div class="well">
                 Side Panel One
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Footer-->
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="well">Hello</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You will just have to play around with the heights to get it to the screensize that works for you.